# Integral of a function $f: \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \to\mathbb{R}$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $X = Y = \mathbb{N}$, $A = B = P(\mathbb{N})$, $\mu$ and $\nu$ counting measures on $(X, A)$ and $(Y, B)$.

Define $f:X\times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(m,m) = 1$, $f(m+1,m) = -1$ and $f(m,n) = 0$ otherwise. Show that $\int(\int f d\mu)d\nu$, $\int(\int f d\nu)d\mu$ both exist and that they are unequal.

I don't really see how these integrals can be unequal, isn't it that in both cases we are doing $1\mu(\{pt\}) - 1\mu(\{pt\})$ where the points are different but they are still just sets with one element?

Comment: HINT: One integral is $0$, and the other is $1$. Look carefully at what happens when you integrate $d\nu$ along $x=0$.

Comment: You may be misunderstanding the statement. $f$ is nonzero on *every* point of the form $(m, m)$ for $m \in \mathbb N$, so $f(1,1) = f(2, 2) = f(3, 3) = \ldots = 1$. It's not that there's some *particular* $m$ for which $f(m, m) = 1$, and for all other $k$, we have $f(k,k) = 0$. Hence in both cases we're doing something more like computing $1 \mu(S) - 1 \mu(T)$ where $S$ and $T$ are countably infinite sets.